# python code to set 3 bits within a byte used for multiple purposes

Tags: python, byte, bit

Evening

I am trying to write some python code for the [las v1.3 specification](http://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/asprs_las_format_v12.pdf)

for efficiency, the specification shares a single byte for 4 different purposes as follows:

- Return Number 3 bits (bits 0, 1, 2)
- Number of Returns 3 bits (bits 3, 4, 5)
- Scan Direction Flag 1 bit (bit 6)
- Edge of Flight Line 1 bit (bit 7)

setting a single bit is the easy part.  The harder part is how to set the 3 bits for 'number of returns', which is a value between 0 and 5.  I could write some dodgy code like this...

```
def setBitsFor_numberreturns(self, int_type, numberreturns):
    if numberreturns == 0:
        return int_type
    if numberreturns == 1:
        int_type = self.bitSet(int_type, 3)
        return int_type
    if numberreturns == 2:
        int_type = self.bitSet(int_type, 4)
        return int_type
    if numberreturns == 3:
        int_type = self.bitSet(int_type, 3)
        int_type = self.bitSet(int_type, 4)
        return int_type
    if numberreturns == 4:
        int_type = self.bitSet(int_type, 5)
        return int_type
    if numberreturns == 5:
        int_type = self.bitSet(int_type, 3)
        int_type = self.bitSet(int_type, 5)
        return int_type
    return int_type
def bitSet(self, v, offset):
    '''
    Set the index:th bit of v to 1 if x is truthy, else to 0, and return the new value.
    '''
    mask = 1 << offset   # Compute mask, an integer with just bit 'index' set.
    v |= mask         
    return v
```

but that seems very non-pythonic.
So my question is this...
Is there a pythonic means to represent a value (say 0-5 at a specific, non-conventional location within a byte?

Comment: Just what do you mean by "set the 3 bits for 'number of returns'"? You seem to mean "set the bits that are `1` in 'number of returns' and leave the others as they were", but it is more likely that it should be "change those bits to equal the corresponding bits in 'number of returns'". I.e. your code now leaves bits that are already set to remain set, but they probably should become the same as the similar bit in 'number of returns'.

Comment: yes. in this example 'number of returns' happens to be the variable name for the data we are trying to store.The existing bits need to remain unchanged as they are used for a different purpose (ie a different variable).  For the purposes of efficiency, the format description packs 4 variables into a single byte. I know my code works, but it is awful clunky, and could be far more elegant.

Comment: That's not what I mean. You say that bits 3, 4, and 5 represent Number of Returns. But if `numberreturns` is 5, your code turns on bits 3 and 5 *and leaves bit 4 alone*. If bit 4 was on, bits 3 through 5 now represent 7, not 5. Is that really what you want, or did you want to turn bit 4 off so bits 3 through 5 now represent 5?